# How to pass form value from model to controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller

I have a modal form that passes value to the model, to controller which will finally run the code to insert to database, but my problem is I don't know how to pass the value from my form to model and to my controller. Here is my model code

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class addbusiness extends Model
{
    //fillable fields
    protected $fillable = ['Fname', 'staffphn'];
}
```

and below is my controller code that insert into database

```
 public function insert(Request $request){
    //validate post data
    $this->validate($request, [
        'Fname' => 'required',
        // 'content' => 'required'
    ]);


   DB::table('business')->insert(
        ['owner_id' => 3, 'bus_name' => 'Fname' ,'address' => 'Fname' ,'phone' => 'Fname' ,'email' => 'Fname' ,'logo' => 'Fname','country' => 'Fname', 'createdon' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s' ), 'createdby' => 'Fname',]
    );
```

As you can see i passed values straight to my database, and not from my form. the insert code works fine

here is my form

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Fname" id="Fname" value="" placeholder="Business Name" required />
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase form-control-feedback"></span>
```

My problem now is that I don't know how to pass the form value to my model and finally to my controller. Any help with proper documentation would be appreciated as am new to laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Business::create([
  'Fname' => $request->get('Fname'),
  ...
]);
```

Or you can use `$request->all()` if the form has all the correct `name` attributes:

```
Business::create($request->all());
```

Your `Model` should just be called `Business` for this to work.